# Can hidden variables save determinism at all?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, determinism, randomness, bohmian-mechanics

It seems to me that HVT (hidden variables theories) were first imagined as a way to escape intrinsic randomness of QM (by this I mean unpredictability, or one-to-many property : one initial condition give many possible results; one being selected randomly for every experiment).

But this seems impossible from the start, as it would amount to say that given some 'classical' variables, there would exist a function that is able to act as a true random generator, and we know that is is impossible (multivariate functions exist, but there is no mathematical way to select one outcome randomly).

In Bohmian mechanics, it seems to me that intrinsic randomness is simply shifted in the initial conditions (eg. the double slit account of Bohmian mechanics : the particle position X(t) has a determinsitic path if X(0) is known, but X(0) is random, and should follow the probability distribution of $\psi^2(0)$).

Am I correct so far?

If so, can we not even disprove Bohmian mechanics? My idea is the following. Instead of considering one 'measurement', consider two in a row. Eg. consider the usual two Stern-Gerlach (SG) experiment : get first a beam of Z+ particles, then pass it through an X-oriented SG. We know from QM that the beam will split again in X+ and X-. But in hidden variable theories, can't we say somehow that the HV have been fixed once and for all given that I look at particles in the Z+ beam? If this is so, then the trajectory in the second SG should be deterministic, and give only X+ or X-, or maybe even something else, not both with some probabilities. To prevent this, we somehow should randomize again the initial conditions after the particle has been detected as being Z+? But then, it would merely be a weird rewriting of standard QM.
What do you think?

Comment: Hidden parameter theories don't say they can produce objectively random phenomena with a few extra classical variables. So such a thing is not even worth debunking. They say that quantum phenomena are not in fact random. Randomness is only an illusion, the result of our incomplete knowledge; like the random motion and distribution of molecules in ideal gases, for example in phase space. So, if we introduce extra variables, the appearance of randomness disappears and we can get all measurement results in a deterministic way.

Comment: Yet they need to introduce randomness to reproduce QM results : hence not being deterministic? Norsen book on Foundations of QM, 2017, chp 7, says : "Indeed, if we experimentally prepare an electron to have wave function psi(x, 0), we
cannot pick or control the exact initial particle position X(0) – this will therefore
be random, and one might expect that there should be some associated probability
distribution P(x, 0) to characterize this." So my understanding is that it is not a lack of knowledge as you put it, in the sense that it is a knowledge that you can't access. Or can you?

Comment: Roughly speaking: A HV interpretation of QM would say that the randomness of QM is of the same nature as the randomness in classical statistical mechanics: epistemic, not ontic. The previous comment is correct. Any good book discussing HV should explain this.

Comment: @AttilaJanosKovacs I think you should consider making your comment an answer to the post. The OP did ask multiple questions, but your answer short circuits them by answering OP's "Am I correct so far?".

Comment: A comment: why would we want to save determinism? After all, we do have exceptionally effective determinist theories (most of physics in fact), and also QM stochasticity, and then a deep mystery about how this is all articulated - which means the natural world has a wonderful depth and richness that transcends our current conceptual frameworks (as it always have, in the history of physics). Why the urge to reduce this depth to plain determinism, which itself just means there is nothing to see here, everything has always been written from the beginning? What a poor picture of the world!

Comment: I don't understand at all most of the comment here; or why the question is closed. From wikipedia : In physics, a hidden-variable theory is a deterministic physical model which seeks to explain the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics by introducing additional (possibly inaccessible) variables. So, it is the purpose of HVT to get rid of randomness, is it not?

Comment: Yes, but you asked something about a "true random generator" or so; I don't see the connection to the Wikipedia statement. You do not explain what exactly you mean with this, nor why you would conclude something like this. I wouldn't close the question for being non-mainstream; I'd close it for not being clear (and neither focused)...

Comment: ok thanks; I guess this is because determinism may have different meanings; I'll clarify later ; what I meant was future = f(past) in the spirit of Cauchy uniqueness theorem.

Answer (score -1):

What is there to save? *I would argue that there is no intrinsic randomness in quantum mechanics*. Such a statement would imply that randomness is unavoidable, even at the level of equations of motion, which is not the case. By [Kraus's second representation theorem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3540127321_26), which follows from the [Stinespring dilation theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2032342) and [Choi's theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379575900750), **all quantum operations, including measurements have a deterministic representation** at the level of equations. The unitary description of measurements implied by this representation corresponds precisely to the time evolution of the system and apparatus during the measurement process, and it implies that all outcomes occur, but we only observe one, because we are classical. I can elaborate on this point if helpful.

The main point here is that there are formulations of quantum mechanics in which there is no randomness at the level of equations. No quantum operation is random, it is only our experience thereof that is random, which is a consequence of things like decoherence or else a fact of nature that we have yet to explain adequately, depending on whom you ask. Also, this may sound like many-worlds, but it isn't...what I've said above is implied by every axiomatic formulation of quantum mechanics.

It's worth noting that hidden-variables (HV) models either fail to eliminate the randomness (e.g., by moving it elsewhere) or else cannot actually describe different experiments with the same model. This is contextuality, where the HV model for the same system depends on what you choose to measure. This is not an acceptable feature of a physical theory, while randomness would be. So this is a downgrade. Also, HV models have to violate relativistic causality, while quantum mechanics itself does not violate relativistic locality, nor does any other physical phenomenon ever observed.

HV models were an attempt to address Einstein's concerns about quantum mechanics. That it should respect relativistic locality and that it shouldn't be intrinsically random. But neither of those concerns actually apply to quantum, as we now know. The theorems I mentioned above were proven after Einstein's death. If anything, Einstein's concerns are more applicable to HV models. They *must* violate locality and they are either random or context dependent, but the description of a system shouldn't depend on what we choose to probe later on. I would say that quantum mechanics is fine as is.

Answer (score -1):

Your question raises several distinct issues.

The first issue is whether Bohmian mechanics is testable. Some advocates of pilot wave theory claim that Born rule statistics happen when particles are in equilibrium with the pilot wave and so that they might sometimes be out of equilibrium and deviate from the Born rule:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10761

In the pilot wave theory both the particles and wave function exist. The wave function undergoes interference in an SG experiment and pushes the particles this way or that.

You can't really say that the pilot wave theory rewrites standard QM because the standard textbook position on QM doesn't make much sense:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973

and in any case it isn't clear that there is such a thing as standard QM since there is a lot of disagreement about QM. What exactly is it rewriting?

If you take quantum theoretical equations of motion seriously as a decription of reality, then you get the Everett interpretation

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

The pilot wave theory takes the Everett interpretation and adds particles on top of it without solving any additional problems:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403094

although some of its advocates have attempted to argue otherwise:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0810